# "no such column" error when trying to update

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update

I am trying to replace a `string` with an `id`:

```
import sqlite3

TABLES = ['table1', 'table2', ...]
PAR_TYPES_STRINGS = ['foo', 'bar', ...]
PAR_TYPES_ID = [1, 2, ...]

def upateTable(table, parTypeId, parTypeString):
  return f"UPDATE {table} SET par_type = {parTypeId} WHERE par_type = {parTypeString};"

conn = sqlite3.connect('existing_db.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

for table in TABLES:
  for index, parTypeString in enumerate(PAR_TYPES_STRINGS):
    parTypeId = PAR_TYPES_ID[index]
    cursor.execute(upateTable(table, parTypeId, parTypeString))
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Returns:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: foo

I am using `par_type` statically as a column name, comparing it to `parTypeString` (which has `foo` in it dynamically).

```
WHERE par_type = {parTypeString} < dynamically passed variable
      ^
      hardcoded column name
```

Yet, it says "no such column foo", which is the first element the `for loop` takes out of `PAR_TYPES_STRINGS`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function definition, you need to put `{parTypeString}` in quotes: `'{parTypeString}'`, because you want to check where the hardcoded column matches that string. Otherwise the expression is interpreted to check equality between two columns, hence the error message.